# React - How to render HTML in source code instead "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, seo, server-side-rendering

Recently I deployed an app to production, when I checked after some days in Google SEO, It's only showing  index.html only in the rendered cached snapshot,

The website has so many pages, so it won't be the easy task to convert app to next JS, can anyone help me, how can I resolve the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body  onload="myFunction()">
<noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div class="main-wrapper" id="root">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks